# Using Scipy to Find Optimal Pairs of a Cost Matrix with an additional Constraint Matrix

Tags: optimization, scipy, linear-programming

I'm working on an optimization problem where I have a set of pairs that need to be assigned, each with associated costs.

I have been using [scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment](https://stackoverflow.com) up to now.

I would now like to increase the complexity of the problem by trying to control the selected pairs with an additional constraint matrix. I want to still minimize the cost of the selected pairs, but now with the constraint that the average value of the selected pairs with respect to a second matrix is kept close to some threshold.

Here's an example using NumPy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

cost_matrix = np.array([[3.1, 3.0], [3.0, 3.1]])

secondary_matrix = np.array([[1.0, 10.0], [10.0, 1.0]])

# Define the threshold for the average value in secondary_matrix
average_threshold = 6.0
```

In this toy example, `cost_matrix` is a square matrix (rarely ever the case) where costs[i][j] represents the cost of pairing pairs[i] and pairs[j]. `secondary_matrix` is a matrix of the same shape, where importance_values[i][j] corresponds to the a secondary cost of pairing pairs[i] and pairs[j]. The average_threshold sets the maximum allowable average secondary cost value for selected pairs.

Using just `scipy.optimize.linear`*`sum`*`assignment`  would give pairs in [0,1] and [1,0], whereas while controlling for the secondary matrix would give the diagonal entries as optimal pairs. This is what I want to achieve in the the optimisation.

I'm seeking guidance on suitable optimization approaches or libraries that can handle this type of problem efficiently. So far, I have implemented this approach:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment, minimize


def match_minimize(cost_matrix, constraint_matrix, average_threshold):
    def combined_objective(x):
        row_indices, col_indices = linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix + x.reshape(cost_matrix.shape))
        total_cost_matrix = cost_matrix[row_indices, col_indices].sum()
        selected_pairs_average = np.mean(secondary_matrix[row_indices, col_indices])
        return total_cost_matrix + max(0, selected_pairs_average - average_threshold)

    # Initial guess for the optimization variable x
    x0 = np.zeros_like(cost_matrix).flatten()

    # Solve the optimization problem
    result = minimize(combined_objective, x0, method="COBYLA")

    # Extract the optimal assignments
    row_indices, col_indices = linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix + result.x.reshape(cost_matrix.shape))
    return row_indices, col_indices
```

In this approach, I add a penalty to the cost when the average of selected values of the secondary matrix is above the average threshold

It seems to work for small matrices, but for my problem I need to work on matrices with thousands of elements, and I get a python segfault when I have a matrix with > 255 column elements.

I am a beginner in optimisation and so am not sure if I'm on the right track or not.

Does my approach with match_minimize seem reasonable? Is there a way to get this to work with larger matrices? Or should I use a different approach?

All recommendations and advice greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: _cost_matrix is a square matrix (rarely ever the case)_ - then why represent it as such? What would the dimensions of a typical rectangular matrix be instead?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I represented it as such for ease of understanding the 2x2 assignment. A typical example would be 1000 x 10 in dimension

Comment: Is it only a coincidence that the example `secondary_matrix` is integral; can it be assumed continuous?

Comment: Yes, editing now -  the aim was to show a large difference in size of matrix elements

Comment: `importance_values` is only mentioned once; is that actually used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward LP construction; though you need a weight parameter to decide how important mean error is with respect to primary assignment cost. Try changing `mean_err_weight` in the following between 0.5 and 1.0 to observe the difference.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import milp, LinearConstraint
import scipy.sparse


def mean_assignment(
    asn_cost: np.ndarray,
    mean_cost: np.ndarray,
    target_mean: float,
    mean_err_weight: float = 1,
) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,  # assignments
    float,  # mean
    float,  # error from mean
]:
    """
    Perform linear sum assignment with a secondary objective of minimizing deviation from a mean;
    in other words,
    minimize sum(asn_cost[assign]) + mean_err_weight*(sum(mean_cost[assign])/n - target_mean)

    :param asn_cost: Assigment costs, 2D
    :param mean_cost: Mean costs; must be same shape as assignment costs
    :param target_mean: Number to which the mean of mean_cost[assign] will be pulled
    :param mean_err_weight: Optimization objective weight for mean cost
    :return: Assignment array of same shape as asn_cost; resulting mean of assigned mean_cost; and
        resulting error from mean
    """

    if asn_cost.shape != mean_cost.shape:
        raise ValueError('Shape mismatch')

    # Ensure a long matrix during optimization
    transpose = asn_cost.shape[0] < asn_cost.shape[1]
    if transpose:
        asn_cost = asn_cost.T
        mean_cost = mean_cost.T

    m, n = asn_cost.shape

    # Variables:
    #    m*n assignments, binary
    #    mean deviance, continuous

    cost_coeff = np.concatenate((
        asn_cost.ravel(),    # Assignment costs
        (mean_err_weight,),  # Cost of error from mean
    ))
    integrality = np.ones(m*n + 1)  # Assignments are binary
    integrality[-1] = 0             # Mean error is continuous

    # There must be at most one assignment per row (Kronecker)
    row_excl = LinearConstraint(
        A=scipy.sparse.hstack(
            (
                scipy.sparse.kron(scipy.sparse.eye(m), np.ones((1, n))),
                scipy.sparse.csc_array((m, 1)),
            ),
            format='csc',
        ),
        lb=np.zeros(m),
        ub=np.ones(m),
    )

    # There must be exactly one assignment per column
    col_excl = LinearConstraint(
        A=scipy.sparse.hstack(
            (scipy.sparse.eye(n),)*m +
            (scipy.sparse.csc_array((n, 1)),),
            format='csc',
        ),
        lb=np.ones(n),
        ub=np.ones(n),
    )

    # The error from mean is taken as the absolute
    # err >= +sum(secondary[assign])/sum(assign) - target
    # err >= -sum(secondary[assign])/sum(assign) + target
    # cost_matrix*assign + ... - n*err <= n*target
    # cost_matrix*assign + ... + n*err >= n*target
    mean_err_abs = LinearConstraint(
        A=scipy.sparse.bmat([
            [mean_cost.ravel(), [-n]],
            [mean_cost.ravel(), [+n]],
        ], format='csc'),
        lb=[-np.inf, n*target_mean],
        ub=[n*target_mean, +np.inf],
    )

    result = milp(
        c=cost_coeff, integrality=integrality,
        constraints=(row_excl, col_excl, mean_err_abs),
    )
    if not result.success:
        raise ValueError(result.message)
    assignments = result.x[:-1].reshape((m, n)).astype(int)
    mean_err = result.x[-1]
    mean = mean_cost[assignments.astype(bool)].mean()
    if transpose:
        assignments = assignments.T
    return assignments, mean, mean_err


def test() -> None:
    assign, mean, mean_err = mean_assignment(
        asn_cost=np.array([
            [5, 2],
            [3, 4],
            [6, 7],
        ]),
        mean_cost=np.array([
            [1., 10.],
            [10., 1.],
            [2.,  2.],
        ]),
        target_mean=6.,
        mean_err_weight=1,  # change to 0.5 to see cost tradeoff
    )

    print(assign)
    print('mean =', mean)
    print('mean err =', mean_err)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Imagine a free variable (our `mean_err_abs`) floating in some positive value, that must be minimized - but minimized to the _absolute_ error. That means we can't only minimize down to a boundary of sum(...) - target; we must also minimize down to a boundary of -(sum(...) - target) so that the boundary itself is always positive.

Comment: Hey thanks for your clear and well-commented code with a great  example. The result is clear
For the creation of `cost_coeff`, an array is made of the flattened (raveled) cost matrix with an extra value concat.'ed at the end, the mean error weight. The integrality is created with the same dimensions (mxn +1). Why the choice to construct the costs this way?
Im having some difficulty to understand the construction of `mean_err_abs`. How  do -n and +n as written contribute to the error from mean,  and then how the error from the mean is actually calculated in the optimisation?  ty

Comment: _Why the choice to construct the costs this way?_ - For low-level LP routines like that of scipy, there is no choice - all variables need to be lumped into one flat array. Higher-abstraction libraries like PuLP etc. can separate these out.

Comment: _How do -n and +n as written contribute to the error from mean_ - those are a result of multiplying out the `/n` from the mean operation to the other terms. The other option would be to just write `[-1], [+1]` (coefficients multiplied to the error term), but you'd have to divide the secondary sum by `n`. Often in MILP constructions multiplication is a better idea than division, keeping the constraint matrix to be round numbers.

Comment: _how the error from the mean is actually calculated in the optimisation?_ - with constraint `mean_err_abs`. There is a subtraction in that matrix between the assigned secondary matrix terms and the target mean.

Comment: To wrap your head around it, I recommend `print(mean_err_abs.A.toarray())` to look at the constraint array. Rows are constraints, columns get multiplied into variables.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed explanations! quite a bit to get my head around indeed but I think I get it now, in parituclar the multiplying out of +n/-n. Ill dig deeper into the code to pick it apart. Thank you very much for the time you spent in helping me! I learned a lot

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for using scipy or moving to something like pulp for this sort of problem?

Comment: Might want to stick with scipy for "things that are already matrix-oriented" like your question. For more complex scenarios that involve slicing and dicing variables over different indices, etc; or when the constraint computations get too confusing in canonical form, PuLP helps. Lots of content on SO for both.